# Clone element with class

Tags: jquery

How to clone content of the element with class and put it into itself?
Here is example. We have this:

```
<div class="cloneThis">one</div>
<div class="cloneThis">two</div>
```

The result must be like

```
<div class="cloneThis">one<span>one</span></div>
<div class="cloneThis">two<span>two</span></div>
```

I tried something like

```
$('.cloneThis', this).append('<span>'+$('.cloneThis', this).html()+'</span>');
```

but it returns first element of class and put it into all other. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.cloneThis', this).each(function() {
 $(this).append('<span>' + $(this).html() + '</span>');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) takes a function, like this:

```
$('.cloneThis').append(function(i, html) { return $('<span>').html(html); });
//or:
$('.cloneThis').append(function(i, html) { return $('<span>', { html:html }); });
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/bHYDe/1/).

Comment: Nice, but you forgot their context argument of `this` (unless they thought they needed it, when in fact they didn't).

Comment: @alex - I don't think it's needed here, but you can change the initial selector to `$(this).find('.cloneThis')` if it is needed :)

Comment: @elrocie - If you're on jQuery 1.4+, it's much faster as well :)

Comment: @Nick, question: is `$(this).find('.cloneThis')` different/faster to `$('.cloneThis', this)`

Comment: @Gaby I'm pretty sure internally they map to the same thing (been a while since I looked at the source).

Comment: @Gaby - `$('.cloneThis', this)` calls `$(this).find('.cloneThis')` internally: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/core.js#L169 so it's more efficient (and clearer, to me, since it's a chain) to do `.find()` yourself.

Comment: Thanks @nick, i didn't bother to look myself.. (*although it is the next and final else that does it :p*)